# React-admin ImageInput / FileInput multiple upload

Tags: image, file-upload, react-admin

I have a problem while using  or FileInput in react-admin.

I used multiple= false OR didn't use multiple

```
<ImageInput
    source="picture"
    multiple={false}
</ImageInput>
```

And i checked picture and got

```
picture: {
   rawFile: "....",
   url: "...",
   title: "..."
}
```

But I used multiple=true and upload many images

```
<ImageInput
   source="picture"
   multiple={true}
</ImageInput>
```

after thet, checked picture and got

```
picture: [
   0: {url: "...", title: "..."},
   1: {url: "...", title: "..."},
   0: {url: "...", title: "..."}
]
```

I need rawFile in every Json object of picture but I don't see them

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you try with the `<ImageField/>` compoenent as provided in the doc ?
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#imageinput

If it doesn't work maybe try to change the save button compoenent and write you own:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#using-onsave-to-alter-the-form-submission-behavior

I usualy write my imge component like that and it work like a charm:

```
<ImageInput {...props} accept="image/*" source="image" multiple={true} >
   <ImageField source="src" title="title"/>
</ImageInput>
```